# Jquery Get Element by ID Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

```
$(function() {
  $(".form_new td select").change(function() {
    alert($('#new_school').id)
  });
});
```

I have the code above in my app. But It keeps on alerting "undefined." What am I doing wrong? #new_school is a textfield. I have already installed jquery. In my public/javascripts folder I have jquery.js, jquery.min.js and jquery.ujs.js. I am using Rails 3.0.9

Comment: can you post your relevant html?

Answer (score 12):

change this: `alert($('#new_school').id)`
to this: `alert($('#new_school').attr('id'))`

Comment: Now. I wanted to hide or display $('#new_school') when the 'change' event of element ".form_new td select" is triggered. How will I do that? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Why it happens:**

In `$('#new_school').id`,
`$('#new_school')` returns a `Array` of elements, and `id` is not defined in the `Array`.
So it will throws you a `undefined`.

**How do you solve it:**

1. `$('#new_school')`**`[0]`**`.getAttribute('id')`, or
2. `$('#new_school').attr('id')`
   (`.attr` will only find the `id` of the first element in the array, read [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr).)
3. `$('#new_school')`**`[0]`**`.id`

**PS:**

PS.: In your script: `alert($('#new_school').id)`
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　**↑**
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 The `id` you finding is right *there*, duh!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
alert( $('#new_school').attr('id') )
```

Answer (score 1):

$('#new_school').attr('id') should work but this is useless because you have to know the id beforehand to select the element.

Usually you only do some like this

```
var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
```

to get the ID of the object that invoked the event